# Neo4j cypher query speed up

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm working on a site that uses Neo4j thorugh a php library. The thing that bothers me is that my suggestions show up quite slowly ( 1-3 seconds ). They should appear almoast instantaneously. I am using Jquery ui Autocomplete for showing results, and the following cypher query:

```
$query = "START n = node:Destination('name:*')
          WHERE  ( n.name =~ '(?i).*".$input.".*' OR n.name2 =~ '(?i).*".$input.".*' ) AND has( n.published )
          RETURN n
          LIMIT 6";
```

Does anyone have any optimization ideas, or can someone tell me what am i doing wrong?

Comment: But what about the actual performance of the query? Did you measure it? Maybe your bottleneck is somewhere else?

Comment: i mesured it. on localhost i got about 110-120ms, on server i got 620ms ( which is very high :( ).

Comment: Can you test how mane results are returned with a count(*)?

Comment: see the discussion on the Neo4j Google Group: https://groups.google.com/d/topic/neo4j/qLVzgjt0Oyc/discussion

Answer (score 0):

why do you search within all Destination nodes and just in the where clause you distinct between the already inserted input? you can put it into to definition clause:

```
$query = "START n = node:Destination('name:".$input."*'),n2 = node:Destination('name2:".$input."*')
          WHERE   has( n.published ) AND has (n2.published)
          RETURN n,n2
          LIMIT 6";
```

could you please measure the times with this query?

Answer (score 0):

Answer from @maxdemarzi

`START n = node:Destination('name:*')`  <-- **bad**

Take a look at the search example here=>
http://maxdemarzi.com/2012/11/14/crunchbase-on-neo4j/

```
query = "name:*#{params[:term]}* OR name2:*#{params[:term]}*"

get '/search' do 
  content_type :json
  neo = Neography::Rest.new    

  cypher = "START me=node:node_index({query}) 
            RETURN ID(me), me.name
            ORDER BY me.name
            LIMIT 15"
  query = "permalink:*#{params[:term]}* OR name:*#{params[:term]}*"
  neo.execute_query(cypher, 
                    {:query => query })["data"].
                      map{|x| 
                           { label: x[1], 
                             value: x[0] }
                         }.to_json   
end
```